# Why does an immutable struct become mutable when moved into a vector?

Tags: rust

still new to Rust and I am learning about the mutability rules of the language. I am trying to understand if structures, objects, arrays are deeply immutable.

So I have this struct

```
struct Foo {
    bar: String,
}
```

And I would like to see what the rules for deep mutability are. When creating the struct, the struct must be defined as `mut` in order for it to have properties changed on it.

```
let mut f = Foo{ 
    bar: String::from("hello") 
};

f.bar = String::from("foo"); // Must be mut to change a property
println!("{:?}", f.bar);
```

However when I define an immutable struct and move it into a mutable vector, the struct becomes mutable.

```
let f = Foo{ 
    bar: String::from("hello") 
};

let mut strings: Vec<Foo> = vec![f];

strings[0].bar = String::from("foo");

println!("{:?}", strings[0].bar);
```

I am guessing that `f` is being copied into the mutable vector (and dropped from it's scope?) and the copy is being reassigned as mutable but I am not really sure.

Can I get some insight into what is going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**`mut` is not a property of the value**. It is a property of the *binding* (I am specifically *not* talking about mutable references, i.e. `&mut`, only `let mut`).

`let v` means "I will not attempt to change the value `v` contains *through `v`*, either directly or indirectly".

But once it's no longer within `v`, i.e. it was moved, it's fine to change it.

The following code, thus, compiles successfully:

```rust
let v = Foo { bar: String::new() };
let mut mutable_v = v;
mutable_v.bar = "abc".to_owned();
```

From the moment we moved the value out of `v`, the mutability of `v` is not relevant anymore.

And in the same manner, from the moment we moved the value out of `f` and into the vec `strings`, the mutability of `f` doesn't matter anymore, but the mutability of `strings` - because we don't change the value through `f` but through `strings`.

Comment: Thank you, this explained everything. In my mind I had coupled the binding and the value together - assuming that the value was defined as immutable by the binding. Question: A mutable borrow `&mut` allows temporary mutable access to a variable, the original variable must be marked as `mut` in order to be eligible for a multiple borrow, right?

Comment: @DavidAlsh Correct. But mutable borrows are more complicated: they _are_ about values at some level.

Comment: I'd also add to say that this is one of the reasons why Rust doesn't really need immutability at the type level like is necessary in many high-level languages (C#, Java, JS, etc.), where you need to guard stuff more carefully. In those languages, if you have a handle to an object, you can change it because there's no such thing as an immutable handle vs a mutable handle (absent interfaces, but downcasting around it is trivial). In Rust you can give something immutable access to something else and know that (absent UB) the value can't be changed by that thing.

Comment: (To be fair, you also have this in C++ with const references. Rust is a bit more rigorous about it -- it's defined behavior in C++ to cast away const-ness of references as long as the referent isn't declared const, but in Rust you can't do this without `unsafe`.)

Comment: @cdhowie In Rust transmuting a shared to a mutable reference is immediate UB. But like I said, references are more complicated. Mutability of variables is basically a lint and has nothing to do with the value. However, mutability of references is a real thing on the Abstract Machine.